# How do I override a parent class's functions in python?

Tags: python, inheritance, overriding, parent

I have a private method `def __pickSide(self):` in a parent class that I would like to override in the child class. However, the child class still calls the inherited `def __pickSide(self):`. How can I override the function? The child class's function name is exactly the same as the parent's function name.

Comment: Please don't use all those `__`'s.  They're confusing.  There's really no "private" in Python.  They make simple things look confusing.  Please update your question with the smallest example of code that shows your problem.

Comment: That is the code I'm having trouble with... what more do you want? I know that "private" functions and variables can still be accessed in Python, but won't using all public functions make things more confusing when using the class?

Comment: "That is the code"?  What code?  Can you update the question to actually provide a sample of actual code that actually doesn't work?  It's very hard to guess at what your code looks like.  It's easy to assume things; it's easy to assume wrong.  "what more do you want?"  Code.  To look at and see what mistake you're actually making, not what mistake I assume you're making.

Comment: human.__pickSide(). That doesn't work in that it was not calling the human.__pickSide() I wanted, it was calling gambler.__pickSide() instead.

Comment: also, in regards to OO talk, Classes don't really have "functions". they have "methods" :P

Comment: @wrongusername I think S.Lott meant in the first comment was to leave out that they are private in the example because it is confusing and irrelevant. In the actual code it is best to keep them because they tell the programmer something, even if it is not enforced by the interpreter.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Let's look at the easiest example:

```
from dis import dis

class A(object):
  def __pick(self):
      print "1"

  def doitinA(self):
      self.__pick()

class B(A):
  def __pick(self):
      print "2"

  def doitinB(self):
      self.__pick()

b = B()
b.doitinA() # prints 1
b.doitinB() # prints 2

dis(A.doitinA)
print
dis(B.doitinB)
```

The disassembly is as follows:

```
  8           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (self)
              3 LOAD_ATTR                0 (_A__pick)
              6 CALL_FUNCTION            0
              9 POP_TOP
             10 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             13 RETURN_VALUE

 15           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (self)
              3 LOAD_ATTR                0 (_B__pick)
              6 CALL_FUNCTION            0
              9 POP_TOP
             10 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             13 RETURN_VALUE
```

As you can see, Python mangles function names that begin with two underscores (and accesses to such names!!) to a name that includes the class name - in this case `_A__pick` and `_B__pick`). That means that the class in which a function is defined determines which of the `__pick` methods is called.

The solution is simple, avoid pseudo-private methods by removing the double underscores. For example, use `_pick` instead of `__pick`.

Answer (score 5):

The problem you're seeing is that the double underscores mangle the function name even in calls. This prevents polymorphism from working properly since the name it is mangled to is based on the name of the class the method is defined in, and not the name of the class of the object that is being referenced. Replacing the double underscores with something else will solve this.

Answer (score 4):

- Using `__foo` names mangles the name of the method to make it more hassle to access it when you need to. I would recommend never using them, which makes things like testing go more smoothly.
- There is no private in Python, and if there was, it would prevent you from doing this anyhow. (This is the point of private stuff in languages that have it.)
- The common convention to indicate that an attribute is not part of the public interface of a class it to use a *single leading underscore*, like `_foo`. This is sufficient for making your code clear separating your internal details from your public API.