# How to call the original method when it is monkey-patched?

Tags: python, oop, python-3.x, monkeypatching, overriding

I have a class in the main project I don't want to change.

```
class A():
    def __init__(self, firstname, lastname):
        self.firstname = firstname
        self.lastname = lastname

    def name(self):
        # this method could be much more complex
        return self.lastname.upper()
```

I'm trying to build a plugin mechansim. So far so good, I have an extension point like this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    ''' The main project has an extension point that allows me to do'''
    # for each class extension such as AExtended:
    A.name = AExtended.name
    ''' After the extensions are loaded, some behaviours may be changed'''
    a = A("John", "Doe")
    print(a.name())
```

A plugin can be written like this:

```
class AExtended(A):
    ''' This is an extension I provide through a plugin mechanism
    '''
    def name(self):
        return self.firstname + ' ' + self.lastname.upper()
```

This all works very well. I now get "John DOE".

My problem is that the original `name()` method can be quite complex. In other words, I can't afford to call `self.lastname.upper()` in the `AExtended`. I'd like to call the "super" method, which does not exist any more, because it has been overwritten.

How can I change my code, in order to achieve something like this:

```
class AExtended(A):
    def name(self):
        # I'm looking for a way to call the base implementation that was in A.name()
        return self.firstname + ' ' + parent.name()
```

Thanks for your help!

Edit: Some explanations of what I try to do.

- I want the plugin to patch the behaviour of `A`. I can't afford to change existing consumers of A
- There are many classes like `A` that could be changed, I'd like plugins to have full control and responsibility
- It's true `AExtended` does not have to inherit from `A`, but it was an easy way to access `self.firstname`. I have no problem following a different design pattern if it can help.

I have a workaround, but it's not very elegant and hard to generalize

```
class AExtended(A):
    def name(self):
        # I'm looking for a way to call the base implementation that was in A.name()
        return self.firstname + ' ' + self.parentname()
#in main
A.parentname = A.name
A.name = AExtended.name
```

Comment: Yes, I read how to [call the parent class method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805066/how-to-call-a-parent-classs-method-from-child-class-in-python) but in `AExtended.name`, `self` is a `A` because of the overriding

Comment: I might be more lcuky with [overriding a private method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2484215/how-do-i-override-a-parent-classs-functions-in-python) but I cannot change the A method name.

Comment: Given your clarifications, I would suggest you change the question title. A more accurate title might be "How to call the original method when it is monkey-patched?"

Comment: @Weeble done. I did not know this was called monkey-patching

Comment: No problem, I just want you to get the best answers possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a full example of what I was hinting at.  Feel free to yell at me and have me merge my answers, or downvote one or whatever, just easier to provide an alternative as a new answer.  I'll let the code do the talking instead of poorly explaining it.  :)

```
## Some shared class that is used all over the place and needs to be patched.

class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.firstname = 'Bob'

    # Print my first name.
    def name(self):
        return self.firstname

    # Use this to allow patching arbitrary methods...
    @classmethod
    def patch(cls, func_name):
        def patch_by_name(new_func):
            old_func = getattr(cls, func_name)
            def patched_func(self):
                return new_func(self, old_func)
            setattr(cls, func_name, patched_func)
        return patch_by_name

## Some other area of the code where you want to throw in a patch

class PatchedA(A):  # doesn't need to subclass, but comes in handy sometimes
    @A.patch('name')
    def name(self, orig_func):
        return 'I am ' + orig_func(self) + 'McWizwaz'

print 'Who are you, A class?'
print A().name()  # prints 'I am Bob McWizwaz'
```

Comment: (And of course, you're free to make it not a classmethod and just a standalone function and call it as `@patch(A, 'name')` instead, thus making it usable for any class anywhere.)

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to do put that `@patch` decorator outside of `A` and also apply it to the patching `def name` _outside_ any subclass? What exactly is the purpose of a subclass `PatchedA` anyway, when you replace the original `A`'s method?

Answer (score 22):

This is what we call a 'decorator' pattern.  Replace the original reassignment of name to have it call a function instead, which takes the original.  It then returns a new function.

```python
def name_decorator(method):
    def decorate_name(self=None):
        return stuff + method(self)
    return decorate_name
A.name = name_decorator(A.name)
```

Later, calling `A.name` will call `decorate_name` with `self` as the current instance and `method` will be available to it which points to the function at the time of the reassignment.

Comment: +1 because python decorators are doing exactly what I want. I'll accept this answer when I can check it can be generalized.

Comment: I use Python 3. What syntax sugar can help?

Comment: See: http://docs.python.org/reference/compound%5Fstmts.html#function - rather than do explicit overrides, you can place `@my_decorator` right before any function def you want to decorate.

Comment: Lemme phrase that better...  `A` would define functions, along with a foo method whose sole purpose is to do what I originally pasted.  It takes a function and returns a closure.  Later, someone can subclass it and put @foo before their `name()` impl, which at runtime causes the patch/punch to happen.  Direct consumers of `A` get the subclass' version w/ out having to touch all that code.

Comment: Decorators syntax exist since python 2.4.

Comment: Yup.  Wanted to give a working example.  People out there still run 2.2!

Comment: Still not sure how to write this as a `@decorator`, as the (inner) function definition seems to happen in the current local scope, before I can bind `method` to the old class method. Any hints on how to produce a working example?

Answer (score 2):

```
class ABase(object):
    def name(self):
        pass

class A(object):
    pass

class AExtension(ABase):
    def name(self):
        return ABase.name(self)

A.name = AExtension.name
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what class should be used. I need to copy all methods from `ABase` to  `A` (`A.name=ABase.name` etc) and then load extensions (`A.name=AExtension.name`)?

Comment: `A` already has all methods of `ABase` because `A` extends `ABase`. But overall the idea of reassigning methods to other class looks suspicious. You might find some ideas how to correctly a minimal plugin architecture in this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/932069/building-a-minimal-plugin-architecture-in-python

Comment: @Skirmantas, it's not uncommon to decorate functions like he wants to do.  Newer versions of the language even support syntactic sugar to make my example even easier to write.

Comment: @Skirmantas Thanks for the pointer (already opened in the past :-). I actually build my plugin mechanism from Mary Alchin's simple plugin framework. I have already a couple of extensions point at strategic places. However, I think it would be overkill to place extension points everywhere (particularly in the model). That's why I'd rather let plugins overwrites some parts if they want to.

Comment: You don't even need to put the patching `def name` in any (sub)class, do you?

Answer (score 1):

One option that might not always be the best in a language like Python is to use the `@override` decorator from [this non-standard package](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/overload/1.1). But this is a viable option only if your two functions work on different types or different number of arguments. Other than that, there's not much you can do, besides renaming your function.

Comment: Interesting package, but I don't see how it can help me :-/

Answer (score 1):

Standing on the shoulders of giants (@spencer), here's a bit more generic sample. It lets one patch a class Original without touching its source code. In this version, parameters fly all over the place, and a reference to an arbitrary context is given to the new method.

```
class Original:
    def f( self, a, b = None ):
        print( "f", a, b )
        self.g( b )

    def g( self, b ):
        print( "g", b )

class Patcher:
    def prepare_class( self, clazz ):
        @classmethod
        def on_class_patcher( cls, func_name, context ):
            def patch_by_name( new_func) :
                old_func = getattr( cls, func_name )
                def patched_func( self, *args, **kwargs ):
                    return new_func( self, old_func, context, *args, **kwargs )
                setattr( cls, func_name, patched_func )
            return patch_by_name

        setattr( clazz, "patch", on_class_patcher )

class Another:
    def log( self, level, info ):
        print( level, info )
```

Now, let's patch something:

```
obj = Original()
obj.f( 1, b = "hello" )

p = Patcher()
p.prepare_class( clazz = Original )

logger = Another()

@Original.patch( "f", context = logger  )
def new_f( self, old_f, context, a, b ):
    print( "new_f", a, b )
    context.log( "zzz", a )
    old_f( self, a, b )

obj = Original()
obj.f( 1, b = "hello" )
```

And the output is:

```
f 1 hello
g hello
new_f 1 hello
zzz 1
f 1 hello
g hello
```