# Python: how to resolve this class inheritance

Tags: python, inheritance, overriding

I have the following classes:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self,x):
        self.x = x
        self.xp = self.preprocess(x)

    def preprocess(self,x):
        return(x**2)

class B(A):
    def __init__(self,x,y):
       A.__init__(self,x)
       self.y = y

    def results():
       return(self.xp + self.y)
```

In this toy example, `A` is used to read some data (`x`) and preprocess them (`xp`).

`B` further reads some data (`y`) and produces a result using the preprocessed data from `A`.

Now I need to create a class `C`. `C` has exactly the same difference as `B`, so I am tempted to
simply define it as:

```
class C(B):
    pass
```

however, I need to override the `A.preprocess()` method, so that the correct preprocessing is used when `C` is constructed. Is there an easy and straightforward way to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I override a parent class's functions in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2484215/how-do-i-override-a-parent-classs-functions-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, just define a new `preprocess` method on `C`:

```
class C(B):
    def preprocess(self, x):
        return x + x
```

The `A.__init__()` method will find *that* method over the one defined in `A` when called with `type(self) is C`.